# Advanced Custom Fields - Checkbox choice from other page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In a page I have a tab that has a checklist of all the hotels that have been made (can be posts or pages – whatever is easiest) . Then the name of the page / post is passed to populate the name of the checkbox (On the admin side in the dashboard) and then when I need to use the information in the code I can do so by searching the database for the rest of the values associated to that particular page.

[image]
[image]

So a post I have created (or another page) can be selected as a checkbox option. That way the information I need from that page/post can be passed across by getting a header value out of it and then searching the database to get the rest of the information.

Is there any way of doing this? If so how would I do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you